# No method/field name found

Tags: rust

I'm trying to apply some OOP but I'm facing a problem.

```
use std::io::Read;

struct Source {
    look: char
}

impl Source {
    fn new() {
        Source {look: '\0'};
    }

    fn get_char(&mut self) {
        self.look = 'a';
    }
}


fn main() {
    let src = Source::new();
    src.get_char();

    println!("{}", src.look);
}
```

Compiler reports these errors, for `src.get_char();`:

> error: no method named `get_char` found for type `()` in the current
>   scope

and for `println!("{}", src.look);`:

> attempted access of field `look` on type `()`, but no field with that
>   name was found

I can't find out what I've missed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Source::new` has no return type specified, and thus returns `()` (the empty tuple, also called unit).

As a result, `src` has type `()`, which does not have a `get_char` method, which is what the error message is telling you.

So, first things first, let's set a proper signature for `new`: `fn new() -> Source`. Now we get:

```
error: not all control paths return a value [E0269]
     fn new() -> Source {
         Source {look: '\0'};
     }
```

This is caused because Rust is an expression language, nearly everything is an expression, unless a semicolon is used to transform the expression into a statement. You can write `new` either:

```
fn new() -> Source { 
    return Source { look: '\0' };
}
```

Or:

```
fn new() -> Source {
    Source { look: '\0' }  // look Ma, no semi-colon!
}
```

The latter being the more idiomatic in Rust.

So, let's do that, now we get:

```
error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `src` as mutable
    src.get_char();
    ^~~
```

Which is because `src` is declared immutable (the default), for it to be mutable you need to use `let mut src`.

And now it all works!

---

Final code:

```
use std::io::Read;

struct Source {
    look: char
}

impl Source {
    fn new() -> Source {
        Source {look: '\0'}
    }

    fn get_char(&mut self) {
        self.look = 'a';
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut src = Source::new();
    src.get_char();

    println!("{}", src.look);
}
```

*Note: there is a warning because `std::io::Read` is unused, but I assume you plan to use it.*

Comment: .. but I've thought Rust has _return type inference_ since many new languages have. Why it doesn't infer the return type of `new` from the line I wrote?

Comment: @deepmax: Rust has type inference *within a function*, but requires functions signatures to be explicit. Even if it did, however, it would conclude that `new` should return `()` because of the semi-colon. The type of `Source { look: '\0' }` is `Source`, but the type of `Source { look: '\0' };` (with semicolon) is `()`.